# Are SDK's mutually exclusive in an Intellij Module?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a mixed scala/python maven module.  I primarily do scala development but in order to do some python work I changed the SDK to python.

Now I can not do scala.  So is there no way to have both be available? Do I need to manually switch back and forth??

[image]

Here is what happened after selecting the python sdk, and attempting to run a scala test class:

[image]

**UPDATE**   It appears the situation is *worse* than anticipated: I can not even switch back to scala at all. Did the project get corrupted??

Here is the error shown in the screenshot:

```
Error:scalac: error while loading package, Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror', required by /Users/steve/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.4/scala-library-2.10.4.jar(scala/package.class)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Python facet, you shouldn't select a Python SDK as the SDK to use for your module or project. It only needs to be selected in the facet settings, as your screenshot shows. The project/module SDK needs to be a regular Java/Scala SDK.

Comment: OK i created new project from scratch, and did it as you say here: setting python only in the facet not the project.Seems OK.